# Removing subviews from UITableViewCell in SWIFT

Tags: swift, uitableview, subview

I have 3 UILabels inside a UITableViewCell, it is causing me problems when I am trying to update the cell and is not updating correctly. I want to be able to remove all subviews from the cells and then create new UILabels and this should work then. How can I remove all subviews from a cell?

Sorry if a bit of a broad question but not sure where to start.

Answer (score 8):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
    for view in yourTableViewCell?.subviews  as! [UIView]{
        if let label = view as? UILabel {
            label.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need this to happen when the viewWillDisappears? Can this be called inside that?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick solution for swift:

```
yourTableViewCell.contentView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
```

Answer (score 0):

it's better if you subclass your UITableViewCell, then you can have outlets (in the custom UITableViewCell class) to the subviews in it. When the method below gets called , you can update it's labels and use conditions for that too:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:CustomUITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as CustomUITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Sorry this ones completely lost me. How do i subclass my UITableViewCell

Comment: you go to File->New->File , choose iOS->Source->cocoatouch class and in class: CustomTableViewCell , subclass: UITableViewCell (choose from drop down menu).

Answer (score 0):

you go to File->New->File , choose iOS->Source->cocoatouch class and in class: CustomTableViewCell , subclass: UITableViewCell (choose from drop down menu).

https://www.dropbox.com/s/17mzkrtgnwdophq/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-09%20at%204.06.50%20PM.png?dl=0

once you have created your custom cell class:

In the storyboard select the prototype cell in the tableview , and in identity inspector you have to set the class of it to CustomUITableViewCell

https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=Screen+Shot+2015-07-09+at+4.07.04+PM.png

and you add your outlets like this which you can reference as i did in the previous answer!

```
class CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var backgroundImage: UIImageView
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel
}
```

hope this helps!